# How can I configure a specific serialization method to use only for Celery ping?

Tags: serialization, celery, python-3.8

I have a celery app which has to be pinged by another app. This other app uses json to serialize celery task parameters, but my app has a custom serialization protocol. When the other app tries to ping my app (app.control.ping), it throws the following error:

```
 "Celery ping failed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type application/x-stjson (application/x-stjson)"
```

My whole codebase relies on this custom encoding, so I was wondering if there is a way to configure a json serialization but only for this ping, and to continue using the custom encoding for the other tasks.

These are the relevant celery settings:

```
accept_content = [CUSTOM_CELERY_SERIALIZATION, "json"]
result_accept_content = [CUSTOM_CELERY_SERIALIZATION, "json"]
result_serializer = CUSTOM_CELERY_SERIALIZATION
task_serializer = CUSTOM_CELERY_SERIALIZATION
event_serializer = CUSTOM_CELERY_SERIALIZATION
```

Changing any of the last 3 to [CUSTOM_CELERY_SERIALIZATION, "json"] causes the app to crash, so that's not an option.

Specs: celery=5.1.2
python: 3.8
OS: Linux docker container

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Changing any of the last 3 to `[CUSTOM_CELERY_SERIALIZATION, "json"]` causes the app to crash, so that's not an option.

Because [result_serializer](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-serializer), [task_serializer](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-serializer), and [event_serializer](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#event-serializer) doesn't accept `list` but just a single `str` value, unlike e.g. [accept_content](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#accept-content)

- The list for e.g. `accept_content` is possible because if there are 2 items, we can check if the type of an incoming request is one of the 2 items. It isn't possible for e.g. `result_serializer` because if there were 2 items, then what should be chosen for the result of task-A? (thus the need for a single value)
- This means that if you set `result_serializer = 'json'`, this will have a global effect where all the results of all tasks (the returned value of the tasks which can be retrieved by calling e.g. `response.get()`) would be serialized/deserialized using the [json-serializer](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#serializers). Thus, it might work for the ping but it might not for the tasks that can't be directly serialized/deserialized to/from JSON which really needs the custom *stjson-serializer*.

Currently with Celery==5.1.2, it seems that task-specific setting of `result_serializer` isn't possible, thus we can't set a single task to be encoded in `'json'` and not `'stjson'` without setting it [globally](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-serializer) for all, I assume the same case applies to ping.

- Open request to [add result_serializer option for tasks](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6310)
- A short discussion in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63448095/11043825)

Not the best solution but a workaround is that instead of fixing it in your app's side, you may opt to just add support to serialize/deserialize the contents of type `'application/x-stjson'` in the other app.

**other_app/celery.py**

```
import ast

from celery import Celery
from kombu.serialization import register


# This is just a possible implementation. Replace with the actual serializer/deserializer for stjson in your app.
def stjson_encoder(obj):
    return str(obj)
def stjson_decoder(obj):
    obj = ast.literal_eval(obj)
    return obj

register(
    'stjson',
    stjson_encoder,
    stjson_decoder,
    content_type='application/x-stjson',
    content_encoding='utf-8',
)

app = Celery('other_app')

app.conf.update(
    accept_content=['json', 'stjson'],
)
```

- You app remains to accept and respond `stjson` format, but now the other app is configured to be able to parse such format.